# Passing parameters though url?

Tags: c#, json, web-services, url, parameter-passing

I am trying to test a call to my one of my functions.

This is called from outside of my website an acts like a Webservice.

To test im trying to pass the parameters though my url.

> http://localhost:0000/APIService/UploadValuationDetails?ValuationDetails=[{property_details_address_address1{TagValue:'Test'},{ImageBase64:''}}]?Id=4785

My code in my service:

```
public void UploadValuationDetails(Dictionary<string, ValuationDetails> JsonResult, int Id)
{
  DatabaseHelper DBH = new DatabaseHelper();

  foreach (var item in JsonResult)
  {                               //(ValuationId , TagName , TagValue , ImageBase64)
    DBH.WSValuationDetailUpdate(Id, item.Key, item.Value.TagValue, item.Value.ImageBase64); 
  }         
}
```

ValuationDetails class:

```
public class ValuationDetails
{
   public string TagValue { get; set; }
   public string ImageBase64 { get; set; }
}
```

Edit Changed ? for the second parameter to &:

---

```
> http://localhost:0000/APIService/UploadValuationDetails?ValuationDetails={'property_details_address_address1':[{TagValue:'Test',ImageBase64:''}]}&Id=4785
```

After changing my url to the one above a break point was hit but the values were incorrect.

[image]

Edit 2 Trying to get the correct values in the json result.

---

I think i'm closer:

```
http://localhost:0000/APIService/UploadValuationDetails?JsonResult={TagName:"property_details_address_address1",ValuationDetails:{TagValue:"Test","ImageBase64:""}}]&Id=4785
```

But now my jsonResult = 0

Comment: When you have multiple parameters, you must separate them with `&`. `?` is only used to separate the pathname from the first parameter.

Comment: I am Writing the Url directly into my browser so i can send screen shots on how i create it.

Comment: Any movement on this?  How are you fairing?

Comment: @paqogomez Nope could not get it right but the app that sends me the data lets it through so luckily i was able to move on. But in terms of placing a json directly into a url did not work. Looking at fiddler it was the same format i was trying to send so i don't know why it did not work. Maybe because you can't set content type = application/json

Comment: @Pomster did you test your json? because it was jacked up.

Comment: @paqogomez Yes i found a json validator on line and it liked my json.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an ampersand (`&`) to separate multiple query string parameters. As you have it, you're using `?`, so "?Id=4785" is being interpreted as part of the value for the `ValuationDetails` parameter.

Corrected:

```
                                       this is correct ┐
                                                       ↓
http://localhost:0000/APIService/UploadValuationDetails?ValuationDetails=
 [{property_details_address_address1{TagValue:'Test'},{ImageBase64:''}}]&Id=4785
                                                                        ↑
                                               but this should be fixed ┘
```

Comment: @Cory Thanks, Fixed that but my values are still wrong, please see my edit.

Comment: @Pomster: Are you sure that the `JSON` you have what .NET is expecting for a `Dictionary<string, ValuationDetails>`? I'm not familiar enough with the inner workings to know whether it is. Also, the parameter value in the URL in your first test is different from the one you just posted.

Comment: @Cory I am typing the Url directly into my browser for testing, i just can't get the pattern right See edit 2 to see what im trying to do.

Comment: @Pomster if you are typing the value directly, why do you tell me that you are not parsing it from the url?

Comment: @paqogomez ?? am am passing it from the url, I type it directly into the url and while my local host is running and a break point is triggered on the function.

Comment: @Pomster, your JSON is invalid as well.  See my edit for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is  better to Encode the JSON too.
Since the moment you will have for instance in side your data an ? or & you will get an exception too.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL string looks improperly formatted.

For the separator of the URL and the parameters you would use `?`.

But to separate parameters use `&`

> http://localhost:0000/APIService/UploadValuationDetails?ValuationDetails=[{property_details_address_address1{TagValue:'Test'},{ImageBase64:''}}]&Id=4785

Your JSON is invalid.

I've worked with it a bit, but it still needs input from you.

```
[
    {
        "property_details_address_address1": {
            "TagValue": "Test"
        },
        "needs_a_name_here": {
            "ImageBase64": ""
        }
    }
]
```

Notice that i've put quotes around the names.  And your second object also requires a name.

I used [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate and create the proper json

Comment: @paqogogomez Thanks But my values are still wrong, please see the screen shot in my edit.

Comment: @Pomster your screen shot doesnt show the value of either parameter.  Post the code that you are using to parse the json.

Comment: I am writing it into my Url

Comment: @Pomster and when the breakpoint is triggered, there is no value in `JsonResult`?

Comment: @Pomster I just pasted your json into a parser and got 5 errors.  Try putting the string `[{property_details_address_address1{TagValue:'Test'},{ImageBase64:''}}]` into [this site](http://json.parser.online.fr/)